# How to send a request to a web service using SOAP xml in Postman?

Tags: xml, soap, postman

I'm trying to integrate my website to a web service that use SOAP xml, but im having trouble doing it. A most of my trouble is understanding the SOAP style and the way it make the requests.

The website that i need to send to is

http://nfse-teste.publica.inf.br/homologa_nfse_integracao/Services?wsdl

What i want to send, as an example is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GerarNfseEnvio xmlns="http://nfse-teste.publica.inf.br/homologa_nfse_integracao/">
      <Rps versao="1.00">
        <InfRps>
          <IdentificacaoRps>
            <Numero>8</Numero>
            <Serie>A1</Serie>
            <Tipo>1</Tipo>
          </IdentificacaoRps>
          <DataEmissao>2012-01-01T21:00:00</DataEmissao>
          <NaturezaOperacao>16</NaturezaOperacao>
          <OptanteSimplesNacional>1</OptanteSimplesNacional>
          <IncentivadorCultural>2</IncentivadorCultural>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Servico>
            <Valores>
              <ValorServicos>1000.00</ValorServicos>
              <ValorDeducoes>10.00</ValorDeducoes>
              <ValorPis>10.00</ValorPis>
              <ValorCofins>10.00</ValorCofins>
              <ValorInss>10.00</ValorInss>
              <ValorIr>10.00</ValorIr>
              <ValorCsll>10.00</ValorCsll>
              <IssRetido>1</IssRetido>
              <ValorIss>10.00</ValorIss>
              <OutrasRetencoes>10.00</OutrasRetencoes>
              <Aliquota>5.00</Aliquota>
              <DescontoIncondicionado>10.00</DescontoIncondicionado>
              <DescontoCondicionado>10.00</DescontoCondicionado>
            </Valores>
            <ItemListaServico>11.01</ItemListaServico>
            <Discriminacao>Teste.</Discriminacao>
            <CodigoMunicipio>3106200</CodigoMunicipio>
          </Servico>
          <Prestador>
            <Cnpj>95836771000120</Cnpj>
            <InscricaoMunicipal>56</InscricaoMunicipal>
          </Prestador>
          <Tomador>
            <IdentificacaoTomador>
              <CpfCnpj>
                <Cpf>04823071964</Cpf>
              </CpfCnpj>
            </IdentificacaoTomador>
            <RazaoSocial>HUGO HAROLDO</RazaoSocial>
            <Endereco>
              <Endereco>DA BAHIA</Endereco>
              <Numero>200</Numero>
              <Complemento>ANDAR 14</Complemento>
              <Bairro>CENTRO</Bairro>
              <CodigoMunicipio>3106200</CodigoMunicipio>
              <Uf>MG</Uf>
              <Cep>30160010</Cep>
            </Endereco>
          </Tomador>
        </InfRps>
      </Rps>
    </GerarNfseEnvio>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

and the error that i'm getting is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Cannot find dispatch method for {http://nfse-teste.publica.inf.br/homologa_nfse_integracao/}GerarNfseEnvio</faultstring>
    </S:Fault>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I'm using Postman to make the request.